# setInterval doesn't seem to work in loops well

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm having problem with intervals in loops.
here is my code:

```
for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
        (function(i){
            set = setInterval(function(){
                alert("hello, world.") // for example.
            },1000);
        })(i);
    };
```

I expect this to happen any 1000 miliseconds, but when it starts it waits for 1000 miliseconds and then execute as usual loop;
i can handle it like this:

```
var i = 0;
    set = setInterval(function(){
        alert("hello, world.");
        i++;
        if(i == 10){
            clearInterval(set);
        };
    },1000);
```

but i don't really want to plan my code in this way.
i gotta use loops.
thanks in advance.

---

why this doesn't work:

```
<div id="lbl"></div><br>
    <script>
    function fun(){
        var text = "in the name of god";
        var lbl = document.getElementById("lbl");
        var arr = new Array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"," ",0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
        for(x in text){
            var spn = document.createElement("span");
            lbl.appendChild(spn);

            for(i=0;i<=arr.indexOf(text[x]);i++){
                (function(i){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        spn.innerHTML = arr[i];
                    },i*200);
                })(i);
            };              
        };
    };
    fun();
    </script>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Scripter - I'm having a hard time understanding WHY you'd want to have a setInteval in a loop this way. Can you provide a bit more explanation about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: becuase i'm dealing with this problem about 2 years :D

Comment: you need setTimeout(fn, i*1000), not setInterval... and you don't need a scope condom if you don't close "i"

Comment: eyval, worked with setTimeout(fn, i*1000); could you plz explain why It works in this way? thanks

Comment: lol, scope condom.. thats hillarious

Comment: What did you expect this to do? You are starting 10 timers that are all going to fire at about the same time (1000 ms). Then they are all going to wait 1000 milliseconds and fire again.

Comment: Because you've been trying two years doesn't answer _why_.  People have been trying to square the circle a lot longer, and I've yet to see a good reason.  :-)

Comment: I'm with Matt Burland--what are you trying to accomplish, and what did you expect to have happen here?  The last time someone asked that question you answered that you're trying to solve the problem for two years--which isn't an answer to the direct question: what are you trying to acccomplish by firing off 10 1000ms timers?

Comment: my script was about to get a text and an element, and then put any word of text in the element in a row BUT strat from a to z, if the current word equals to current loop value stop and then go to the next word. COMPLEX :S

Comment: I can't see a need for timers to achieve something like that. Why don't you post the actual code you have?

Answer (score 0):

You need to invert this--let the timer drive the loop, not the loop drive the timer.
Based on your example:

```
<label id="lbl"></label><br>
<script>

function ok(a){
    var arr = new Array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    var lbl = document.getElementById("lbl");
    var i = 0, iMax = arr.indexOf(a);

    function next()
    {   
        lbl.innerHTML = arr[i];
        if (++i <= iMax) {
            setTimeout(next,i * 200);
        }                
    }
    setTimeout(next,0);
}
ok("z");
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, good idea, you know I need my code to get a string and an element, then start from the frist word in string and do this for it, when equals to the given word, stops and then go to another word til all the words in the string are put in the element, got me? excuse me for my bad english

Comment: Yes, I got that--but I've positioned you to accomplish that.  My job is not to do your job. ;)

Comment: i didn't want you to do my job, I told you my plan